# How to query relations in global scope in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I successfully created a global scope in Laravel and I want to query a relation model in the global scope. I have a Video model, a Category mode, and a VideoCategory pivot model and I want to access the category model using video model in the global scope, such as:

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class DefaultScope implements ScopeInterface{

public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $model = $builder->getModel();

    $builder->whereHas('categories', function( $q ){
        $q->where('language', 2);
    });
}

public function remove(Builder $builder)
{

}
}
```

Is that a possible thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **don't do that**.

How to? Use manual joins, but again, don't.

It will lead to errors, unexpected behaviour, and you will quit it as soon as you got it work.

Eloquent creates new query for a model in so many places, that using `has` is impossible, what you have already noticed, I suppose. Using manual joins would let you do that for given model, but would also break 90% of relation based features of Eloquent, ie. you couldn't use `has` or `with` towards this model etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I`ve already use joins and the result is very satisfying. Although I was not able to use it in the global scope, instead I use it in the model scope, which also forced me to rewrite all my model queries.

Ive notice that using whereHas and Has is very slow, so I used joins + scopes. One thing is sure, I will never use whereHas and Has again.

Comment: Sounds interesting. How do you know `has` and `whereHas` is slow? Comparing to what exactly?

Comment: Compare to joins, `whereHas` and `has` are slow in performance. Ive experienced it in 4.1 before I arrived in this thread. [link]https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3543